# How to bring the Edit functionality

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am facing a problem, i have a tab application in which i made the second controller as a navigation controller and just drag and dropped a table view over this.

My table is working fine with all the elements coming in from the database.

My problem is that i want a edit button when clicked,the table goes into the editing mode and  would allow me to delete rows from the table. I am not able to understand how can i do that i tried this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;



    [super viewDidLoad];
```

It brings a edit button on the right side of the navigation controller but when i click it doesn't changes the table in editing mode.

I know i have to implement this method but i am not getting what to write in this

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

}
```

Everywhere on other forums i find written tableview ----- , what is this table view is it a instance for the UITableView class ?

Help me out in the code stuff 
Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to asign the following button in the *- (void)viewDidLoad*

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

and then implement the following methods:

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove your `setEditing:animated:` or call `super`. The default implementation of `UITableViewController` already puts its table view into editing mode, so you don't have to do that yourself. What you've done here is to override this behavior with a method that does nothing.